# function inside a setTimeout gives undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, for-loop, angular5

I want to set some wait time after each api calling. So I have added setTimeout for api calling in for loop but it giving api service that is `createAPIService` undefined in setTimeout. Below is my code.

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.fooditemselecteddetails.length; i++) {
  this.spinnerService.hide();
  setTimeout(function() {
    this.common.createAPIService('api/booking/AddConcessions?CinemaId=' + this.cinemaid + '&TransactionId=' + this.temptransaction.TransactionId + '&ItemId=' + this.fooditemselecteddetails[i].id + '&Quantity=' + this.fooditemselecteddetails[i].quantity + "&BookingId=" + this.transactionAPIRequest.ORDER_ID, '')
  .subscribe((result: any) => {

      this.spinnerService.hide();
      this.addconcession = result;
      console.log(this.addconcession);


      if (this.addconcession.IsSuccess == true) {

        if (i == this.fooditemselecteddetails.length - 1) {
          localStorage.setItem("bookingid", this.transactionAPIRequest.ORDER_ID);
          this.common.createAPIService('api/booking/FinalBookingDetails?BookingId=' + this.transactionAPIRequest.ORDER_ID, '').subscribe((result2: any) => {
            this.vistavalidation = result2;
            if (this.vistavalidation.BookingID > 0) {
              this.common.createAPIService('api/booking/ContinueTransaction?CinemaId=' + this.cinemaid + '&TransactionId=' + this.temptransaction.TransactionId, '').subscribe((result3: any) => {
                if (result3.IsSuccess) {
                  this.ContinueTransactionresult = result3;
                  this.showTabOnClick('tabs-4');
                } else {
                  this.common.ShowNotification("Food Item", result3.Error, "info");
                  this.spinnerService.hide();
                }
              });
            } else {

              this.common.ShowNotification("Food Item", 'something went wrong, please try again', "info");
              this.spinnerService.hide();
            }
          });
        }
      } else {
        this.common.ShowNotification("Food Item", result.Error, "error");
        this.spinnerService.hide();

      }
    });
  }, 2000);

  console.log(this.addconcession);

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1):

Try using arrow function syntax to retain the scope of **`this`**

**`setTimeout(() => {`** instead of **`setTimeout(function() => {`**:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.fooditemselecteddetails.length; i++) {
  this.spinnerService.hide();
  setTimeout(() => { ... }, 2000);

  console.log(this.addconcession);

}
```

Comment: It's not applying on each api call..I want to set some time between each loop. Now after this time all api calls at once

Comment: Why exactly are you using a `setTimeout` in the first place though?

Comment: There is for loop as per loop api hits. So all api hits at one time if there is foodlength is 5 then 5 time api calls at one time. So because of this server throwing error so I want to set some time between each loop

Answer (score 1):

Use arrow function i.e. `setTimeout(()=>{ },1000)`. It will inherit the `this` of the parent and you would be able to access all methods and variables of class using `this`.

Comment: It's not applying on each api call..I want to set some time between each loop. Now after this time all api calls at once

Answer (score 0):

replace this  "s**etTimeout(function(){**  " to  "**setTimeout(()=> {** ".

Answer (score 0):

When you use the arrow function you create a closure.  A closure is an inner function that has access to the outer (enclosing) function's variables—scope chain. The closure has three scope chains: it has access to its own scope (variables defined between its curly brackets), it has access to the outer function's variables, and it has access to the global variables.

More detail here: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/